How can I loosen the nuts for drain trap slip joints?
I have been trying to remove the P Trap to clean it. I can turn the 1 on my right to loosen it. However, for the 2 on the left, I can’t seem to loosen it. It won’t budge left or right. Do I need a plumber’s wrench? Also which direction should I be turning it?
Thank you


My preference is for channel locks when needed.  Usually with plastic drain piping it should only be hand tight, so once you get it loose don't tighten it too much.  I have converted to plastic for this reason-it is much easier to get tight than metal.

Generic comment irrespective of which answer you favour. Do not use generic mineral oil (including penetrating oil) on plastic, it often has enough of a solvent effect to make things worse by slightly softening the plastic.

Use a large pliers or pipe wrench if you can't turn it by hand. Lefty-loosey, righty-tighty (from the perspective of the part without the male threads--top down for #1 and bottom up for #2).

Use any wide-mouth turning tool, such as a pipe wrench, footprint, strap wrench, multi-grips.

Fully undo 1 before 2.
It may be the angle of the photo, but it looks like the whole trap is at a slight angle. When threads are subject to an angular misalignment, they will bind, so make sure the piping is fully relaxed before you attempt to loosen the stuck nut.

It was just the image was at a weird angle. Thank you!

There is a slight dogleg at 1. Unfortunately this isn't correctable since the trap arm is cemented. I don't think it's enough to be a problem, though.
